# How to assert failure if string is in JSON response from http request JMeter

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I am trying to write a test that ensures that the `name` property in a JSON response is not `MYGROUP`. I'm stuck here because I'm trying to use the code from a test that checks that the `name` property is `MYGROUP`. I know I need to fix something in the if condition of this test:

```
      # Check AD group deletion
      - url: ${ADSubscriptions}/${NetworkID}/clientsyncs/${syncId}/groups
        label: 1360_CheckADGroupDeletion
        method: GET
        headers:
          Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}
          Content-Type: "application/json"
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        assert-httpcode:
          - 200
          - 202
        jsr223:
          - langauge: groovy
            execute: after
            script-text: |
              import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
              def slurperresponse = new JsonSlurper().parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
              for (entry in slurperresponse){
                if(entry.name == "MYGROUP" || entry.name == "mygroup" ){
                   {RETURN FALSE HERE}
                   break;
                }
              }
          - langauge: groovy
            execute: after
            script-file: jsr223/logger.groovy
            parameters: check_adgroup_deletion
```

The expected json structure for the request used in the test looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "id1",
        "name": "MYGROUP",
        "selected": true
    }

]
```

The above response would equate to a failing test. The below would equate to a passing test.

```
[
    {
        "id": "id1",
        "name": "MYGROUP",
        "selected": false
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you're looking for is `prev.setSuccessful(false)` where `prev` stands for the parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance.

See the above JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article to learn more about [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for JSR223 blocks.

In particular your case it would be easier to use `assert-jsonpath` [Taurus assertion](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Assertions)